# Memory does not get allocated with the MAP_ANONYMOUS and MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE flag in mmap()

Tags: c, linux, unix, mmap

I am trying to allocate memory blocks with MAP_ANONYMOUS flag, but it is not creating any memory blocks along with MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE flag, but MAP_ANONYMOUS with MAP_PRIVATE or MAP_SHARED flags creates the blocks of memory. Could someone explain why this happens.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  size_t size = getpagesize();

  errno = 0;
  void *first = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                     MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE, -1, 0);
  printf("first: %p %s\n", first, strerror(errno));

  errno = 0;
  void *second = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                      MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
  printf("second: %p %s\n", second, strerror(errno));

  return 0;
}
```

has been observed to print, on both Linux 4.19 and Linux 5.8,

```
first: 0xffffffffffffffff Invalid argument
second: 0x7f56b274d000 Success
```

The flags *seem* to be getting passed down to the kernel accurately...

```
$ strace -e trace=mmap ./a.out 2>&1 | tail -n5
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd3145bb000
first: 0xffffffffffffffff Invalid argument
second: 0x7fd3145bb000 Success
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: In your code sample, there is no difference between mmap calls (but then I'm not sure what you wanted to showcase with 2 calls). Also, your `printf` calls access out of bounds memory, as you haven't provided an argument for `%p` format. If `mmap` returns `-1`, you should look at `errno` and see what the error is first.

Comment: Note that the second call to `mmap` may change the value of `errno`, so you need to look at it _immediately_ after each `mmap` call, something like: `uint8_t *first = mmap(...); printf("first: %p %s\n", (void *)first, strerror(errno));` (repeat for second).

Comment: @ zwol, I got segmentation fault.

Comment: You got a segmentation fault with _exactly_ the `printf` call I wrote there?  Because I don't.

Comment: I can reproduce the behavior reported (`mmap` failing, not the segfault) on Linux 5.8 and I have absolutely no idea why.  `errno` is `EINVAL`.  As best I can tell from the manpage, `MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS` should be a valid combination of flags.

Comment: Does your kernel support `MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE`? The man page says "since Linux 4.15".

Comment: @zwol  If you run your test process under `strace`, what arguments get passed to the kernel for each `mmap()` call?

Comment: @ Ian Abbott , Yes.  4.19.0-11-amd64

Comment: @AndrewHenle Edited into question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at [`do_mmap`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9/source/mm/mmap.c#L1366) in [linux/mm/mmap.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9/source/mm/mmap.c) (kernel version 5.9), `MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE` only seems to be supported for file-backed mappings (see the [`if (file)`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9/source/mm/mmap.c#L1444) and [`else`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9/source/mm/mmap.c#L1509) sections). I do not know if that is a bug or if it is intentional.

EDIT: I have submitted a [bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209683).

Comment: It seems like a bug.  Certainly the man page doesn't give any hint of this behavior.

Comment: @NateEldredge I submitted a bug report anyway. :)